# Sort a DataTable on converted value of a column

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I am working on an ASP.Net app in C#. I need to sort rows in a DataTable on the converted value of a column called 'Price', which is for some unknown reason, a string type column in the DataTable.

The code snippet below will give me a sorted DataTable on the string value of Price column, but what I am looking for is sorting on the Decimal value of Price column.

**Question**:  What expression would I need to use for the second parameter of `Select` method in this code snippet? Right now, this parameter has a value of `Price asc`.

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
dt = dt.Select( null, "Price asc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).CopytoDataTable();
```

**UPDATE 1**

I was able to make a minimal change in above code-snippet and yet use a decimal value of Price to sort on. I used the  `Convert` function to convert the string value of Price column to a Decimal type. This function is supported in DataTable expressions. Details of this function can be found at this location: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

The code that works is as below.

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
//define an expression column for decimal version of Price
dt1.Columns("Price1").Expression = "Convert(Price, 'System.Decimal')"
dt = dt.Select( null, "Price1 asc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).CopytoDataTable();
```

***Convert Function Example*** for converting value in a column called 'total' to Decimal typeis a below. the second parameter to convert function must be the name of .Net type to which you want to convert and it should be enclosed in single quotes.

```
myDataColumn.Expression="Convert(total, 'System.Int32')"
```

Comment: I tried to convert the column inside DataTable using Convert inside expression exactly the way you wrote it here before I answered, but it's not working. "Cannot find column Convert(Price"

Comment: @msmolcic, I will check again and let you know. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @msmolcic, I edited the code under UPDATE1 and I have verified that it works. The idea is to use DataTable expression to create a calculated column and then sort on the calculated column.

Comment: Adding another column to insert values converted to decimal and order by new column is even more messy than my LINQ solution, but oh well it's your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best idea would be for you to convert those values to decimal, order them and copy them back to table:

```
dt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"])).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I cannot make that change since I am maintaining an existing code-base. May be some cast function may be possible in my situation. Else I will have to use LINQ.